# woocommerce set subscription start date

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

Using WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin:

I'm looking for a way to automatically make the start date (and therefore end date) of a simple subscription.

We've tried renewal sync of payment dates but for various reasons we've changing to subscriptions that don't renew but only last for 1 year. A new order would then be needed after that (there were issues with renewals for this customer).

The customer wants all subscriptions to expire on 31-dec, no matter when they bought it.

I assume there's a way to do it through the functions.php file but I can't find any documentation that helps.

Does anyone know how we can modify the start date when an order is created?

Thanks.

Comment: do you got any solution on this??????

Comment: Please post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// validate the start_date field
if ( ! is_string( $args['start_date'] ) || false === wcs_is_datetime_mysql_format( $args['start_date'] ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_subscription_invalid_start_date_format', _x( 'Invalid date. The date must be a string and of the format: "Y-m-d H:i:s".', 'Error message while creating a subscription', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) );
} else if ( wcs_date_to_time( $args['start_date'] ) > current_time( 'timestamp', true ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_subscription_invalid_start_date', _x( 'Subscription start date must be before current day.', 'Error message while creating a subscription', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) );
}
```